Key-Value pairs that define a position (x,y) for drawing
I want to draw triangles, and would like to pass Key-Value pairs that define positions such as (0,0), (3,0), and (1.5,2.6).  Is there any mechanism to do such a thing ? That is, to pass three arguments to l3keys with each one being a position (x,y).
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\manitu} { O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { manitu_keys } { #1 }

    \tikz { \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (1.5,2.6) -- cycle; }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\end{document}


It would make more sense, imho, to use pgfkeys here.

what have you tried, this seems to require just a basic key definition surely? a={0,0}, b={3,0}, c={1.5,2.6}  then  \draw (\wherever_you_saved_a) -- (\wherever_you_saved_b) -- (\wherever_you_saved_c) -- cycle; possibly expanding it.

Why do you never use your custom commands in yours questions? Please show us the desired syntax.

Expected to be more complicated than what you suggested,  Now there is also the possibility of using pgfkeys.  Although I think that for simple  shapes, using pgfkeys is not so advantageus.

Would the basic key-definition use a tl ?

you have used l3 keys since you know about \keys_set:nn  just define a key you don't need anything special but as @cfr says tikz is fundamentally an application written in pgf using pgfkeys so if the usage is specifically for tikz using pgf will be more consistent, but if you are using l3 keys elsewhere you can of course mix the two

Have used l3 keys but have only stored a single value in a key.

@Franklin that's all you need.

There really doesn't seem any question here other than the most basic key setting, saving the supplied value in a macro.

\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { manitu_keys }
{
   a .tl_set:N = \l_manitu_a_tl,
   b .tl_set:N = \l_manitu_b_tl,
   c .tl_set:N = \l_manitu_c_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\manitu} { O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { manitu_keys } { #1 }

    \tikz { \draw (\l_manitu_a_tl) -- (\l_manitu_b_tl) -- (\l_manitu_c_tl) -- cycle; }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\manitu[a={0,0}, b={3,0}, c={1.5,2.6}]

\end{document}


I can't really see how this syntax is any simpler than the original tikz syntax and it's certainly less documented.

I think there should be a conversion rate for comments to ticks.

pgfkeys lets you set up keys which take multiple values, so you can say triangle={#1}{#2}{#3}, for example.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{%
  /manitu/.cd,
  triangle/.code n args=3{%
    \tikz \draw (#1) -- (#2) -- (#3) -- cycle;
  },
  circle/.code={%
    \tikz \draw  circle [radius={#1}];
  },
  square/.code={%
    \tikz \draw (0,0) -| ++(#1,#1) -| cycle;
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand \manitu { +O {triangle={-1,-1}{1,-1}{0,1}} }
{%
  \pgfkeys{%
    /manitu/.cd, 
    #1
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  \manitu
  \manitu[triangle={2,0}{3,1}{4,5},circle={10mm},square={25mm}]
\end{document}



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

For a triangle I don't see the advantage of using a key=value syntax at all. I'd simply use
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\manitu} { mmm }
  {
    \tikz { \draw (#1) -- (#2) -- (#3) -- cycle; }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\manitu{0,0}{3,0}{1.5,2.6}
\manitu{0,0}{5,0}{1.5,2.6}
\end{document}

If you absolutely want to stick to a key value interface then go ahead though. Maybe I can convince you to use expkv-cs for its ease of setup for macros taking only a few keys (disclaimer: I'm the author of expkv-cs):
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\usepackage {tikz}

\ekvcSplit\manitu{a={0,0}, b={3,0}, c={1.5,2.6}}
  {\tikz\draw(#1)--(#2)--(#3)--cycle;}
\begin{document}
\manitu{}
\manitu{b={5,0}}
\end{document}

Output of both:

